# Could not find function "rasterize_terrain"

Tags: r, lidr

I'm new to R so forgive me if this is obvious. I'm using lidR to create a dtm of a single laz file via kriging and whenever I put in the function

```r
dtm<-rasterize_terrain(las, algorithm = kriging(k=40))
```

it comes back with "could not find function 'rasterize_terrain'". I updated the package and checked the documentation because I know there's a few deprecated functions but they all seem to say this is the way to do it.

Comment: Can you include the rest of your code as well? You are importing the package using library('lidR'), correct?

Comment: You need to add the lidR package `library(lidR)` or invoke the function from the package environment `lidR::rasterize_terrain`. I checked, at version 4.0.0 the function can be called and it is also still in the development version https://github.com/r-lidar/lidR/blob/master/R/rasterize_terrain.R so, not depreciated.

Comment: The issue was the package that was loading from CRAN was not the most recent. I installed it from the github with Rtools and it seems to be working now. Thanks!

Comment: lidR v4.0.0 is available on cran for all platforms.